# Antlr not producing a visit method for some reason

Tags: antlr, antlr4

The following grammar, in Java, does not produce a visitor with "visitExpr" and I have no idea why... I added valueExpression and it DOES produce visitValueExpression, but this doesn't make it easy to get an expr out of all the math expressions.

```
grammar Txml;

program: statement (NEWLINE statement)* NEWLINE? EOF;

statement: require    # Condition
    | entry           # CreateEntry
    | assignment      # Assign
    ;

require: REQUIRE valueExpression;

valueExpression: expr;
expr: lhs=expr ('*' | '/') rhs=expr          # MulDiv
    | lhs=expr ('+' | '-') rhs=expr          # AddSub
    | lhs=expr '%' rhs=expr                  # Mod
    | lhs=expr '^' rhs=expr                  # Pow
    | '(' expr ')'                           # Parens
    | NUMBER                                 # NumberLiteral
    | IDENT '(' args ')'                     # FunctionCall
    | IDENT                                  # Identifier
    | STRING_LITERAL                         # StringLiteral
    ;

functionArgument: expr;
args: (functionArgument (',' functionArgument)*)?;

// Reserved words
REQUIRE: 'require';

// Whitespace and line break
NEWLINE : [\r\n];
WS: [ \t] + -> skip;

// Entities
NUMBER: ('0' .. '9') + ('.' ('0' .. '9') +)?;
IDENT: [a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*;
STRING_LITERAL : '"' (~('"' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n') | '\\' ('"' | '\\'))* '"';
```

Also, I don't quite see how to visit a "generic" node in the base visitor - how do I get a RuleNode out of a specific context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] does not produce a visitor with "visitExpr" and I have no idea why

When [labelling](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) a parser rule `r`, no `visitR(...)` will be generated. Only the `visit...()` methods of the alternatives will be generated.

So without alt labels:

```
r
 : a 
 | b
 ;

// Only 1 method:
//  - visitR(...)
```

With alt labels:

```
r
 : a #altA
 | b #altB
 ;

// Two methods:
//  - visitAltA(...)
//  - visitAltB(...)
```

> Also, I don't quite see how to visit a "generic" node in the base visitor - how do I get a RuleNode out of a specific context?

You could override the `AbstractParseTreeVisitor<T>#visitChildren(...)` method to listen to any rule. A quick demo:

```java
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String source = "require a + b";
    TxmlLexer lexer = new TxmlLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
    TxmlParser parser = new TxmlParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    ParseTree root = parser.program();
    new TestTXmlVisitor().visit(root);
  }
}

class TestTXmlVisitor extends TxmlBaseVisitor<Object> {

  @Override
  public Object visitChildren(RuleNode node) {
    System.out.println("visited: " + node.getClass().getSimpleName() + " -> " + node.getText());
    return super.visitChildren(node);
  }
}
```

will print:

```
visited: ProgramContext -> requirea+b<EOF>
visited: ConditionContext -> requirea+b
visited: RequireContext -> requirea+b
visited: ValueExpressionContext -> a+b
visited: AddSubContext -> a+b
visited: IdentifierContext -> a
visited: IdentifierContext -> b
```